# Changing a dimension always immediately resets to 0

Tags: dimensions

I have an object that was originally imported as an .svg, but I converted it to a mesh. However, blender still will not allow me to give it a size for the third dimension. The file can be downloaded from [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZp6MeXZOvtjlv9HaQYbOqlTENspIS3syFPV).

What is it about this object that prevents me from setting a non-zero value for its Y dimension (in the 'n' dialog)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'give it a size'.  What are you trying to do to give it thickness?  Your example file just contains a plane with four vertices, and if I use a solidify modifier, or extrude the plane it works.  The plane is called "Curve.011" but it's not actually a curve.

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions work as a scale multiplier. As your mesh has a Y dimension of 0, you can multiply it by any number, the result will always be 0.

To get thickness you need to enter edit mode, select all and press E to extrude the faces.

Once the object has Y dimension different than 0 you will be able to vary it in the N panel.

Be aware that you have the snap option activated.